# how can I make an element show in front of youtube video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

I have this youtube video with a link that I want to appear infront of it.

```
<embed id="myVideo" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/f4K6ZxDwi34?version=3&enablejsapi=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="390">

<a id="over" href="javascript:document.getElementById('myVideo').stopVideo();">Stop</a>
```

I have tried inserting `wmode=opaque` or `wmode=transparent`. Still nothing. somebody please assist me.

here is my jsfiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/uprosoft/Av9bp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning. Check [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Av9bp/1/):

Absolute positioned items will automatically be on top of statically positioned items. You can use left and right css attributes to position the element relative to the nearest parent element with postion set to relative or absolute, or the body if no relative/absolute parent is found.